# Addition of ArrayList values having same Date

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I am having a sorted ArrayList like-

```
List<DD_Details> list = new ArrayList<DD_Details>();
list.add(new DD_Details(26/05/2014,3000.00));
list.add(new DD_Details(26/08/2014,6000.00));
list.add(new DD_Details(26/08/2014,2000.00));
```

DD_Details Class is -

```
class DD_Details {

    private Date ddSubmissionDate;
    private Double amount;

    public DD_Details(Date n, Double s) {
        this.ddSubmissionDate = n;
        this.amount = s;
    }

    public Date getDdSubmissionDate() {
        return ddSubmissionDate;
    }

    public void setDdSubmissionDate(Date ddSubmissionDate) {
        this.ddSubmissionDate = ddSubmissionDate;
    }

    public Double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(Double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "ddSubmissionDate: " + this.ddSubmissionDate + "-- amount: "
                + this.amount;
    }
}
```

i just want to add amount values of the same date and store in a new ArrayList.

I tried below code but it is not working properly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Double amt = 0.0;
    Date date1 = list.get(i).getDdSubmissionDate();

    for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {

        if (date1.equals(list.get(j).getDdSubmissionDate())) {
             amt = amt + list.get(j).getAmount() + list.get(i).getAmount();
        } else {
              amt = list.get(i).getAmount();
        }
    }
    list1.add(new DD_Details(date1, amt));
 }
```

Please give me some hint to get it done. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What means "below code but it is not working properly." any exception or the result is not the expected result?

Comment: You need to expand upon "not working properly". What *exactly* isn't working properly? What is it currently doing, and what *should* it be doing?

Comment: Just a suggestion, whenever u get stuck with the code, not working, proceed step by step. Try to debug the code or add logs to figure out the issue. This is will hone your programming skills & trust me you yourself will fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use next solution instead:

```
  List<DD_Details> list = new ArrayList<DD_Details>();
  List<DD_Details> list1 = new ArrayList<DD_Details>();
  list.add(new DD_Details(new Date(2014, 5, 26), 3000.00));
  list.add(new DD_Details(new Date(2014, 8, 26), 6000.00));
  list.add(new DD_Details(new Date(2014, 8, 26), 2000.00));

  for (DD_Details currentEl : list) // iterate over 'list'
  {
     DD_Details existingElement = null;
     for (DD_Details el1 : list1) // find element in 'list1' with the same date
     {
        if (el1.getDdSubmissionDate().equals(currentEl.getDdSubmissionDate()))
        {
           existingElement = el1;
           break;
        }
     }
     if (existingElement == null) // if element is not found in 'list1' then add current element to list
     {
        list1.add(currentEl); // or list1.add(new DD_Details(el.getDdSubmissionDate(), el.getAmount()))
     }
     else // if element is found, then increase amount
     {
        existingElement.setAmount(existingElement.getAmount() + currentEl.getAmount());
     }
  }

  // 'list1' contains what you need
```

Answer (score 1):

In the inner for, when you are adding the values for a particular date, there is an error in the `else` part. You try to iterate through the list for a given date and add all the values until the date is different. Once you reach this condition, you get inside the `else` and set the sum to be the amount of the first element of this given date, therefore you are overriding the sum you had calculated. Moreover, for every new element with the same date, you are adding the amount of the first date, which means that if there are 4 elements of the same date, you will be adding 3 times the first amount.

What you should do, is get the amount for that given date before entering the second loop. One final consideration, is that you are going to get different amounts for different dates because imagine you have 3 elements with the same date, with the loop you are using, you will start with the first one, get the amount of the 3 elements added, then go to the second and get the amount of the second and third added, and finally move to the last one and create a third element with the amount of only the third element. Therefore, you should create a third variable which I called `k`, and store the last `j` value that contained the same date, to then add it to `i` and avoid iterating through an element with a date you already processed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Double amt = list.get(i).getAmount();
    Date date1 = list.get(i).getDdSubmissionDate();
    int k = 0;

    for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {

        if (date1.equals(list.get(j).getDdSubmissionDate())) {
            amt = amt + list.get(j).getAmount();
            k = j;
        }
    }
    list1.add(new DD_Details(date1, amt));
    i += k++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dates should be String literals. The way you've written them they will be ints and all equal to 0.

The obvious solution would be to build a Map of dates to amounts (instead of a list) and after adding all the entries iterating the map to build your list. Something like:

```
  Map<Date, Double> amountPerDate = new HashMap<>();
  List<Date> dates = ...;
  List<Double> amounts = ...; // wherever those may come from
  for(int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i++) {
    Double currentAmount = amountPerDate.get(dates.get(i));
    double amount = currentAmount == null ? 0 : currentAmount;
    amountPerDate.put(dates.get(i), amount + amounts.get(i));
  }
  List<DD_Details> details = new ArrayList<>();
  for(Entry<Date, Double> e : amountPerDate) {
    details.put(new DD_Details(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
  }
  // optionally, you may Collections.sort(details); the list
```

In your DD_Details class, consider using a primitive `double` instead of a boxed `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your problem is in your second for-loop in the else-part of the if-statement. Even if you have dates which match you will have some dates which will not match. Thus you set back your amount the the amount of i.

You should add:

```
System.out.println("The dates are equal. New amount is: " + amt);
```

to your if-statement and:

```
System.out.println("Dates do not match. " + amt);
```

Now you should see that you add the amount the correct way but you reset it in the else part several times.